# How to separate digits

Tags: sum, numbers, zero

I need to separate the numbers of 01234567 and do some operations for that. And i have problem becouse of 0.

```
int num=01234567;
printf("%d,num);
```

why result is 342397 and not 01234567?

Comment: Are you using C?

Comment: Question is not clear and you don't specify a language

Comment: Off topic: `printf("%d,num);` -> `printf("%d",num):`

Comment: Sry, i am using C. This is my first question so i am the new guy here.

Answer (score 1):

A leading `0` indicates the number is in [octal format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Remember that leading zeroes don't exist in internal representations, that any number in your code is often rendered out as a binary value that discards whatever formatting might have been applied. `2.000000` becomes `2` and `0000001` becomes `1`.

If you want things formatted to a particular number of places in human-readable form, you can always opt-in for zero padding:

```
printf("%08d\n", 1234567);
```

Comment: but i must have in code that num=01234567 and separate digits. How i can separate if PS doesnt see that number as that.

Comment: Delete your leading `0`. This isn't difficult.